# Emacs hang after installing GTK3 in windows 7

Tags: microsoft-windows, gtk3

I was led to this place by @Chris from stackoverflow. My original question and steps I have taken (thanks to Chris' suggestion) and outcomes are at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972920/emacs-hang-after-installing-gtk3-in-windows-7. Basically under windows 7, emacs setup was fine until I installed GTK3+ for windows 7. Then emacs hang while starting. The menu appears but everything else not.

My original intent is to learn common lisp, and specifically use cl-cffi-gtk package. Now it looks like that I have to do this under linux using a VM.  It bugs me a lot since my main working environment is windows 7. Thanks a lot.

Sorry that I can't use gtk3 as tag because of lack of reputation.

Comment: Sorry I am still new here, so I don't know the proper format to self-answer: I have got the solution to this problem after filing a bug report in emacs. I think it might be beneficial for any others who want to develop gtk3 using emacs under windows.

Comment: To use gtk3 with emacs under microsoft windows  (7 at least): One has to use the image ports from ezwinports first. You only need the libsrvg and its required dependences: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/. And install them into the emacs (I use 24.5) directory. (All credits go to Eli Zaretskii from debbugs.gnu.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I just saw the "Answer your question" Button. So I copy the above solution in my comments here.

To use gtk3 with emacs under microsoft windows (7 at least): One has to use the image ports from ezwinports first. You only need the libsrvg and its required dependences: sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files. And install them into the emacs (I use 24.5) directory. (All credits go to Eli Zaretskii from debbugs.gnu.org).

Comment: How do I declare this to be closed/solved?

Comment: Click the check-mark on your answer -- it will show up on mouse-over.